# jQuery DataTables requested unknown parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable, datatables

I've having a hard time figuring out why this doesn't work... So the jsfiddle will work.

[jsfiddle working](http://jsfiddle.net/CSUqZ/)

Now the jsfiddle works because I have created a var exactly to what `console.log(data)` in the code below produces.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#<%= ddlProduct.ClientID %>").change(function (e) {
        var P_ID = $("#<%= ddlProduct.ClientID %>").val();
        $.ajax({
            headers: {
                Accept: "*/*"
            },
            type: "POST",
            url: "../service/product.asmx/GetProduct",
            data: '{"jsondata" : {"P_ID" : "' + P_ID + '"}}',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (msg, status, metaData) {
                var data = msg.d.P_ID;
                buildMyDatatable(data);
            },
            error: function (ex, status) {
                //alert(ex.responseText);
                alert("error");
            }
        });
    });

    function buildMyDatatable(data) {
        console.log(data);
        $("#table_id").dataTable().fnDestroy();
        $('#table_id').dataTable({
            "bProcessing": true,                
            "aoColumns": [
                    { mData: "Q_ID"},
                    { mData: "Business" },
                    { mData: "Product" },
                    { mData: "QuestionType" },
                    { mData: "Question" },
                    { mData: "Answer" },
                    { mData: "AskBy" },
                    { mData: "AnsBy" },
                    { mData: "AnsByEmail" },
                    { mData: "DateAsk" },
                    { mData: "DateAns" }
                ],
                "aaData": data,
        });
    }
});
```

My question is, why does `var data = server.hardcoded.response` work vs it not working when using the actual ajax response?

When using the ajax response I get this error.

```
DataTables warning (table id = 'table_id'): Requested unknown parameter 'Q_ID' from the data source for row 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem.

```
var data = $.parseJSON(data);
```

inherently JavaScript was passing it as a string and not an object.